# Mysql Query Optimization for this particular query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I am having a mysql query which is taking roughly 2.6s to execute. At first it was not using index. Now I added index to it. But still no improvements. Any suggestion on this:

```
select posummary0_.id                               as col_0_0_,
       popayment1_.status                           as col_1_0_,
       posummary0_.id                               as id1_11_,
       posummary0_.created_at                       as created_2_11_,
       posummary0_.created_by                       as created_3_11_,
       posummary0_.is_active                        as is_activ4_11_,
       posummary0_.updated_at                       as updated_5_11_,
       posummary0_.updated_by                       as updated_6_11_,
       posummary0_.uuid                             as uuid7_11_,
       posummary0_.additional_cost                  as addition8_11_,
       posummary0_.additional_cost_note             as addition9_11_,
       posummary0_.approved_at                      as approve10_11_,
       posummary0_.approved_by                      as approve11_11_,
       posummary0_.can_be_rejected                  as can_be_12_11_,
       posummary0_.close_reason                     as close_r13_11_,
       posummary0_.closed_at                        as closed_14_11_,
       posummary0_.closed_by                        as closed_15_11_,
       posummary0_.delivery_fee                     as deliver16_11_,
       posummary0_.eta_date                         as eta_dat17_11_,
       posummary0_.sku_farmer_id                    as sku_far35_11_,
       posummary0_.gr_price                         as gr_pric18_11_,
       posummary0_.invoice_date                     as invoice19_11_,
       posummary0_.is_vat                           as is_vat20_11_,
       posummary0_.payment_due_date                 as payment21_11_,
       posummary0_.payment_source                   as payment22_11_,
       posummary0_.po_discount                      as po_disc23_11_,
       posummary0_.po_number                        as po_numb24_11_,
       posummary0_.po_price                         as po_pric25_11_,
       posummary0_.po_status_id                     as po_stat36_11_,
       posummary0_.po_status_update_at              as po_stat26_11_,
       posummary0_.po_summary_payment_type_id       as po_summ37_11_,
       posummary0_.po_summary_type_id               as po_summ38_11_,
       posummary0_.po_vat_type_id                   as po_vat_39_11_,
       posummary0_.receipt_id_type                  as receipt27_11_,
       posummary0_.reject_reason                    as reject_28_11_,
       posummary0_.rejected_at                      as rejecte29_11_,
       posummary0_.rejected_by                      as rejecte30_11_,
       posummary0_.revised_at                       as revised31_11_,
       posummary0_.revised_by                       as revised32_11_,
       posummary0_.total_price                      as total_p33_11_,
       posummary0_.vat                              as vat34_11_,
       posummary0_.warehouse_id                     as warehou40_11_,
       posummary0_.warehouse_distribution_center_id as warehou41_11_,
       posummary0_.warehouse_kitchen_id             as warehou42_11_,
       posummary0_.warehouse_time_window_id         as warehou43_11_
from po_summaries posummary0_
         left outer join po_payments popayment1_ on (posummary0_.id = popayment1_.po_summary_id)
         cross join sku_farmers farmer2_
         cross join warehouses warehouse3_
         cross join po_status postatus4_
where posummary0_.sku_farmer_id = farmer2_.id
  and posummary0_.warehouse_id = warehouse3_.id
  and posummary0_.po_status_id = postatus4_.id
  and (1 is null or posummary0_.is_active = 1)
  and (null is null or posummary0_.created_at >= null)
  and (null is null or posummary0_.created_at <= null)
  and (null is null or posummary0_.eta_date >= null)
  and (null is null or posummary0_.eta_date <= null)
  and ('' is null or '' = '' or farmer2_.uuid = '')
  and ('' is null or '' = '' or warehouse3_.uuid = '')
  and ('%%' is null or '%%' = '' or postatus4_.code like '%')
  and ('%%' is null or '%%' = '' or posummary0_.po_number like '%')
  and (null is null or null = '' or posummary0_.created_by like null)
order by posummary0_.created_at desc
limit 160, 20;
```

the id field are already indexed. I additionally added index on this:

```
create index test_index_2 on po_status (code);
```

Before index explain output:
[image]

After index it became like this:
[image]

I am very new to mysql and need suggestion to improve performance.

**One keynote: If I remove order by then the query execution time becomes so less.**

Can anyone suggest me optimization for this query?
Plan: [image]

Comment: Why do you use `CROSS JOIN` if you have conditions in `WHERE` clause those make this joins to work as `LEFT JOIN`? What is purpose of `WHERE` clause conditions like `1 is null`,  `null is null`, `posummary0_.created_at >= null`, `'' is null`, `'' = ''`, `postatus4_.code like '%'`, `null = ''`, `posummary0_.created_by like null` and so on?

Comment: Is's from DB log...it will be populated by value if have them......that's why..... @Alexey . Like the `1 is null` , 1 will be populated by some value if we use filtering on them

Comment: I definitely don't like it. If values ​​are not set for use, the corresponding conditions must be removed. Also do you have indexes on the foreign keys of the `po_summaries` table?

Comment: yeap using mysql. So, foreign keys are already indexed.(innodb)

Comment: Try to remove all 'noise' conditions, use `LEFT INNER JOIN` instead `CROSS JOIN`. In this case you'll have the only one condition in `WHERE` clause, that is `posummary0_.is_active = 1`, others would be used in `ON` clause of the `LEFT INNER JOIN`s. Than you can add index on the `po_summaries.is_active` column. Also add index on `po_summaries.created_at` as you use it to order the data. Check if it would be faster.

Comment: And share the query execution plan, please

Comment: Is this some "query-generating program"?  To improve this query, we need to make significant changes to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Alexey - `CROSS` + `WHERE` ==> `INNER JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @Alexey but this is same right? CROSS + WHERE is the same as INNER and as far as I know both acts like same. And don't have any performance advantage.

Comment: Whoops, I meant @Alexey -- `LEFT` is used when the "right" table is optional, but you want to keep the row anyway (and all columns show as NULLs).

Answer (score 3):

(I think that is the worst programmatically generated SQL that I have ever seen.  What program created it?  Still, it might actually work as it stands!)

This one composite index may be a partial salvation:

```
posummary0_:  INDEX(is_active, created_at)
```

and when may have to change

```
and  (1 is null
              or  posummary0_.is_active = 1
           )
```

to

```
and  posummary0_.is_active = 1
```

(`OR` is deadly for performance.  This `OR` comes from a lazy query-generator.)

If you feed it different options, you may need another INDEX.

After cleaning up the query, we can talk about turning it inside-out.  This will allow the `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET`, and `LIMIT` to occur *before* all the `JOINs`.  Currently the query is doing 57414*4 joins.  With the reformulation, it will need only 10*4.

**Inside out**

First, see if this provides the desired 20 ids and runs 'fast':

```
select  posummary0_.id
    posummary0_.is_active = 1
    order by  posummary0_.created_at desc
    limit  160, 20;
```

Then build a query something like

```
SELECT ...  -- mostly as above
    FROM ( the 4 lines above ) AS x
    JOIN ...   -- the rest of the SQL, but without the LIMIT
```

Comment: nope...no luck...optimizer is using the same plan

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi - I made 2 changes to my Answer.

Comment: what did you meant by tuning inside out? Can you please explain?

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi - I added a little.